# "add from media library" tab is super slow

Tags: media-library

The add from media tab for wordpress is *super slow* on my local. It takes at least a full minute for the modal box to load content when I click that tab. I am guessing it is because I have 65 pages of images and WP is loading all 65 pages.

Is there a good plug-in or a hack out there to help speed up content loading when adding feature images to posts from the medial library?

Thanks.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. then test again. Then activate your theme again and test ... again. Then activate one single plugin, test again, repeat with the next plugin, test until you found the plugin that's responsible for slowing down your system.

Comment: As an augmentation to what @kaiser said, it might be a combination of plugins causing the issue, so if you don't find a single plugin that's causing it, check for plugin conflicts.

Comment: thanks, found it. Weird thing: didn't affect the rest of the instal just that media tab.

Comment: @Nadine So: What was it? Might be interesting for later readers.

Comment: It was a plugin called Media Library Categories.

Comment: @kaiser Wish there was a way to force everyone to follow that process before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found: The issue was the Media Library Categories plugin.